# Reassign std::function with std::bind during execution

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

I'm trying to implement a logic in my code for which I have several backup mechanism if a certain approach fails.

```
class Foo
{
 public:
    Foo() { func = std::bind(&Foo::f1, this); }

    void f1()
    {
        func = std::bind(&Foo::f2, this);
        // ... (computation which may or may not produce a result)
        bool computation_succeeded = false;
        if(computation_succeeded)
            result_produced = true;
    }

    void f2()
    {
        func = std::bind(&Foo::f3, this);
        // ... (computation which may or may not produce a result)
        bool computation_succeeded = false;
        if(computation_succeeded)
            result_produced = true;
    }

    void f3()
    {
        //computation which for sure produce a result
        result_produced = true;
    }
    
    void execute()
    {
        while(!result_produced)
        {
            func();
        }
    }
    
    std::function<void()> func;
    bool result_produced{false};

};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.execute();
}
```

Basically by calling f.execute() first the "approach" f1 is tried, then, if it did not produce a result (for various possible reasons) it will try the approach f2 by binding that function to the same func variable, and the same reasoning for f3 (which will produce a result for sure).

This code compiles, but I have doubts on two things:

- Could rebinding the func variable while it is being executed to a new function result in undefined behaviour?
- I read that when binding something to an std::function dynamic memory allocation may happen. Does rebinding this way cause any memory related problem?

Comment: @mch I know, it was just for the sake of the example. Anyway I edited the code to make it clearer and able to compile.

Comment: I don't know why my comment was removed, but let me say it again: your example do not need `std::function`

Answer (score 0):

> *I read that when binding something to an std::function dynamic memory allocation may happen. Does rebinding this way cause any memory related problem?*

That is true, `std::function` can be inefficient. When unsure, inspect the generated assembly.

`gcc 10.2 -O3` results: [godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9q6cMK9zE) (NB: clang results are similar)

**main:**

```
        push    r12
        mov     edi, 24
        push    rbp
        sub     rsp, 88
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+48], 0
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+64], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+16], 0
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rax
        movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsp]
        lea     rbp, [rsp+32]
        mov     ecx, OFFSET FLAT:std::_Function_handler<void (), std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*))()> >::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, std::_Any_data const&, std::_Manager_operation)
        movdqa  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+32]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+56]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+16], rbp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], OFFSET FLAT:Foo::f1()
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+8], 0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+48]
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+32], xmm0
        movq    xmm0, rcx
        movhps  xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+16], rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+24], rdx
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp], xmm1
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+48], xmm0
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L48
        mov     edx, 3
        mov     rsi, rsp
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    rax
        jmp     .L48
.L68:
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L67
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    [QWORD PTR [rsp+56]]
.L48:
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rsp+64], 0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+48]
        je      .L68
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L59
        mov     edx, 3
        mov     rsi, rbp
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    rax
.L59:
        add     rsp, 88
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
.L67:
        call    std::__throw_bad_function_call()
        mov     rbp, rax
        jmp     .L44
        mov     r12, rax
        jmp     .L52
main.cold:
.L44:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+16]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L45
        mov     edx, 3
        mov     rsi, rsp
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    rax
.L45:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+48]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L47
        lea     rsi, [rsp+32]
        mov     edx, 3
        mov     rdi, rsi
        call    rax
.L47:
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    _Unwind_Resume
.L52:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+48]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L53
        mov     edx, 3
        mov     rsi, rbp
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    rax
.L53:
        mov     rdi, r12
        call    _Unwind_Resume
```

So already we see dynamic allocation, exception handling, and `Foo::f1` is not inlined...

**Foo::f1():**

```
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi
        mov     edi, 24
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+16], 0
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rax
        movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsp]
        mov     ecx, OFFSET FLAT:std::_Function_handler<void (), std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*))()> >::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, std::_Any_data const&, std::_Manager_operation)
        movdqu  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbx+24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+16], rbx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], OFFSET FLAT:Foo::f2()
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+8], 0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx+16]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx], xmm0
        movq    xmm0, rcx
        movhps  xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+16], rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+24], rdx
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp], xmm1
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+16], xmm0
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L33
        mov     edx, 3
        mov     rsi, rsp
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    rax
.L33:
        call    do_actual_work()
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbx+32], al
        add     rsp, 40
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
        mov     rbp, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+16]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L35
        mov     edx, 3
        mov     rsi, rsp
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    rax
.L35:
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    _Unwind_Resume
```

Yikes, again a memory allocation, conditional jumps, dynamic dispatch *and* exception handling...

**Foo::f2():**

```
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi
        mov     edi, 24
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+16], 0
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rax
        movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsp]
        mov     ecx, OFFSET FLAT:std::_Function_handler<void (), std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*))()> >::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, std::_Any_data const&, std::_Manager_operation)
        movdqu  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbx+24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+16], rbx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], OFFSET FLAT:Foo::f3()
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+8], 0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx+16]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx], xmm0
        movq    xmm0, rcx
        movhps  xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+16], rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+24], rdx
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp], xmm1
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+16], xmm0
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L23
        mov     edx, 3
        mov     rsi, rsp
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    rax
.L23:
        call    do_actual_work()
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbx+32], al
        add     rsp, 40
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
        mov     rbp, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+16]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L25
        mov     edx, 3
        mov     rsi, rsp
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    rax
.L25:
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    _Unwind_Resume
```

Again, exact same story.

**Foo::f3():**

```
    push    rbx
    mov     rbx, rdi
    call    do_actual_work()
    mov     BYTE PTR [rbx+32], 1
    pop     rbx
    ret
```

OK much better, not much to see here.

**Now let's try it without `std::function`...**

```
bool do_actual_work();

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() { }

    bool f1()
    {
        return do_actual_work();
    }

    bool f2()
    {
        return do_actual_work();
    }

    bool f3()
    {
        return do_actual_work();
    }
    
    void execute()
    {
        if (f1())
            return;
        if (f2())
            return;
        f3();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.execute();
}
```

Generated assembly: [godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KGr6nMxjn)

```
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    do_actual_work()
        test    al, al
        je      .L7
.L3:
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L7:
        call    do_actual_work()
        test    al, al
        jne     .L3
        call    do_actual_work()
        jmp     .L3
```

**That's the entire program!**

**Moral of the story:** do not use `std::function` unless it's unavoidable. It's unavoidable for example when you're writing a shared library and you need to take a user-provided callback in a generic way.